# Value STRING_TOO_LARGE of type

Tags: java, android, json, string

I have one  string that is not converting into json array:

```
 {
        \"mantra\": \"प्रातः एवं सांयकालमा आरतीगर्दा भन्ने श्लोक\",
        \"mantra_detail\": \"ॐ जय जगदिश हरे, प्रभु जय जगदिश हरे \n ”प्रभुका चरण उपासक”  ”हरिका चरण उपासक” कति कति पार तरे ।। १ ।।  \nॐ जय जगदिश हरे \n \nमनको थाल मनोहर ”प्रेमरुप वाती”२ ।। प्रभु ।। \n”भाव कपूर छ मड्डल”२ आरती सब भाती ।। २ ।। \nॐ जय जगदिश हरे \n \nनित्य नीरञ्जन निर्मल ”कारण अविनाशी”२ ।। प्रभु ।। \n”शरणागत प्रतिपालक”२ चिन्मय सुखराशि ।। ३ ।। \nॐ जय जगदिश हरे \n \nसृष्टि–स्थिति, लयकर्ता, ”त्रिभुवनका स्वामी”२ ।। प्रभु ।। \n”भक्ति सुधा वर्षाउ” ”प्रेम सुधा वर्षाउ” \n शरण पर्यौं  हामी ।। ४ ।। \n ॐ जय जगदिश हरे \n \nआसुरभाव निवारक, ”तारक सुखदाता”२ ।। प्रभु ।। \n”गुण अनुरुप तिमी हौ”२ हरिहर औ धाता ।। ५ ।। \nॐ जय जगदिश हरे \n \nयुग युग पालन गर्छौ, ”अगणित रुप धरी”२ ।। प्रभु ।। \n”लीलामय रस विग्रह”२ करुणा मूर्ति हरि ।। ६ ।। \nॐ जय जगदिश हरे \n \nसमता शान्ति प्रदायक, ”सज्जन हितकारी”२ ।। प्रभु ।। \n”चरण शरण अब पाउ”२ प्रभु भव भयहारी ।। ७ ।। \nॐ जय जगदिश हरे \n \nभाव मनोहर देउ, ”साधक फलदायी”२ ।। प्रभु ।। \n”जीवन धन्य बनोस्”२ प्रभु पद सेवा पाई ।। ८ ।। \nॐ जय जगदिश हरे \n \nसंयम सुर–सरिताको, ”अविरल धार बहोस्”२ ।। प्रभु ।। \n”जति जति जन्म भएपनि” जहा जहा जन्म भएपनि” \n प्रभुमा प्रेम रहोस् ।। ९ ।। \n ॐ जय जगदिश हरे \n \nप्रेम सहित शुभ आरती, ”जसले नित्य गर्यो”२ ।। प्रभु ।। \n”दिन दिन निर्मल बन्दै” ”प्रतिदिन पावन बन्दै” \nत्यो भव सिन्धु तर्यो ।। १० ।। \nॐ जय जगदिश हरे, प्रभु जय जगदिश हरे..\"
    },
```

My code:

```
private Observable<List<MantraDTO>> getMantraObservable() {
    return Observable.just(1).map(integer -> getMantraList(getMantraStringFromXml()));
}

public String getMantraStringFromXml(){
    return  getActivity().getString(R.string.mantra);
}

public  List<MantraDTO> getMantraList(String mantraString) {
    List<MantraDTO> mantraList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONArray mantraJsonData = new JSONArray(mantraString);
        int length = mantraJsonData.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            mantraList.add(parseMantra(mantraJsonData.optJSONObject(i)));

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this give me error:

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value STRING_TOO_LARGE of type
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
>           at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
>           at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:96)
>           at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:108)
>           at   com.toyanathpatro.gurkha.fragments.MantraFragment.getMantraList(MantraFragment.java:153)
>           at com.toyanathpatro.gurkha.fragments.MantraFragment.lambda$getMantraObservable$0$MantraFragment(MantraFragment.java:106)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: is this a String or an Object?

Comment: Consider using `StringBuilder` when using too large strings.

Comment: This isn't valid JSON. You are escaping the quotes around strings. Remove those (e.g., `\"mantra\":` should be `"mantra":`) and see if it works.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the json data. I something going wrong in  `Observable.just(1).map(integer -> getMantraList(getMantraStringFromXml()));`. because i tried this json data and parsed as well. It's working fine. I can get list with `mantra` and `mantra_detail`.

Comment: i have some other small string also .there nothing wrong with them in same format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will remove character like "\" chars from that string.
   json = json.replace("\\"","'"); JSONObject jo =    new     JSONObject(json.substring(1,json.length()-1));